# Steady state distribution overdetermined linear system

Tags: distributions, linear, markov-process, invariance

I am trying to find the steady state distribution of the transition matrix given by the discrete and time-homogeneous Markov Chain with state space $S \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$. The transition matrix is the following:
$$P=\left|\begin{array}{ccccc}1 / 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 / 2 & 0 \\ 1 / 2 & 1 / 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 / 4 & 1 / 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 / 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 / 2 & 1 / 4 & 1 / 4\end{array}\right|$$ With the aid of computational tools(quantecon package), i've managed to find that the steady state vector $\pi$ equals: $$\pi=\left(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0\right)$$

**However**, when trying to solve $$
\pi=\pi P
$$ subject to $$
\pi_{0}+\pi_{1}+\pi_{2}+\pi_{3}+\pi_{4}=1
$$ i came across the overdetermined system: $$
\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
-1 / 2 & 1 / 2 & 1 / 4 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 / 2 & 1 / 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 / 4 \\
1 / 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 / 4 \\
0 & 0 & 1 / 4 & 0 & -3 / 4 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
\pi_{0} \\
\pi_{1} \\
\pi_{2} \\
\pi_{3} \\
\pi_{4}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{array}\right]
$$ Which i tried to solve by using **np.linalg.lstsq**. The answer given by NumPy was:
$$\operatorname{array}([2.28689719,1.3709223,0.86916554,0.57995555,0.22107943]))$$ which does not correspond to the solution initially mentioned. What am i doing wrong? I suspect it has something to do with the rank of the matrix, but i am not sure. Whatever the reason may be, the calculations should give the same result.

Thanks in advance, Lucas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, i was looking at the output the wrong way. I took a closer look at the documentation, which is provided at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html, and realized that i was looking at the wrong output parameters. The first array produced by the output is the one containing the solution for the overdetermined system and i ignored it for some reason. There was indeed a little error in the augmented matrix, but i fixed it already.